# Embedding DirectX (.x files) in WPF application C#

Tags: c#, wpf, directx

I have DirectX .x files and I would like to display the model in WPF form.

Any suggestions how to do so?

Thanks, 
    Ronny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any case, you'll need to initialize Direct3D, and setup a D3D rendering system.  The most flexible route would be to use [D3DImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.aspx).

Comment: Thanks,
I followed the D3DImage walkthrough and got a hosting window of the directX.
But how do I load the .x file to display and set the camera?

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on working with .X files in D3D here: http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article2079.asp

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response. Unfortunately I'm not so strong in C++ and I can't really understand how to pass the parameters from the WPF to the DirectX engine.